# Using TypeReference with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

The following test fails with

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to org.dabd.mapping2.MapperImplNGTest$Foo
java.lang.ClassCastException
    at org.dabd.mapping2.MapperImplNGTest.testFromMap(MapperImplNGTest.java:82)
```

The only solution I could find is to change the fromMap signature to `T fromMap(S map, Class<T> clazz)` but I don't think it is necessary to pass the class explicitly.  Isn't the TypeReference enough information to instantiate the type T?  Thanks.

```
import java.util.Map;

public interface Mapper<T extends Object, S extends Map<String, Object>> {
    public S toMap(T obj);
    public T fromMap(S map);
}


import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapperImpl<T extends Object, S extends Map<String, Object>>
        implements Mapper<T, S> {

    public S toMap(T obj) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(obj, Map.class);
        return (S) map;
    }

    public T fromMap(S map) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T obj = objectMapper.convertValue(map, new TypeReference<T>() {
        });
        return obj;
    }

}
```

Test

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class MapperImplNGTest {

    public static class Foo {

        private String a;

        public String getA() {
            return a;
        }

        public void setA(String a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

    }

    public MapperImplNGTest() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testFromMap() {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("a", "aa");

        MapperImpl<Foo, Map<String, Object>> mapper = new MapperImpl<Foo, Map<String, Object>>();
        Foo foo = mapper.fromMap(map);
        assertEquals(foo.getA(), map.get("a"));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not use type variables like `T` this way with `TypeReference`: you must pass actual parameterization. This is because there is no runtime information whatsoever associated with `T` here: it is just a placeholder. So it is effectively treated as `java.lang.Object`.

But you can build structured types programmatically using `TypeFactory` (instance of which is available via `ObjetMapper.getTypeFactory()`). You will still need `Class` instances that represent key and value types, but with this information it is possible to construct `JavaType` values that contain full type information that you need.

Comment: Can you show working code that uses `ObjectMapper.getTypeFactory()` that solves my problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at its method for constructing `JavaType`s. For example, to get equivalent of `Map<String,Integer>`, you'd use `JavaType siMapType = typeFactory.constructMapType(Map.class, String.class, Integer.class)`. And then pass this along instead of `TypeReference` or `Class`. Rest, as they say, is left as an exercise to reader...

Comment: I tried this before but the problem is that my type T is a generic POJO. Which typeFactory.construct* method should I use?

Comment: If it's not a `Map`, array or `Collection`, you should use `constructParametricType`

Comment: Can you show me a test case where this works? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
public T fromMap(S map, TypeReference<T> typeReference) { 
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        T obj = objectMapper.convertValue(map, typeReference);
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers, helped me a lot.
I have gone with this solution, hope that could help someone too:

```
import com.app.entity.dto.YourDTO;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.MapLikeType;
import java.util.Map;

public class YourConverter {
    public static Map<String, Object> toMap(final YourDTO yourDTO) {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final MapLikeType mapLikeType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
        return objectMapper.convertValue(yourDTO, mapLikeType);
    }
}
```